# HOW to echo New record with selected old record in PHP Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I am new in PhP. I have a query

```
"SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= 338
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 2";
```

Result of My query is

[image: query]

Now i want to print first row of of resulted query and i success. But now i want to echo only two columns `ltitle` and `Stitle` from second row. Here i failed.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$id2 = $_GET['id'];
$sql= "SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= 338
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//$array = array('1','2','3');

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td> ID </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['client_id'] ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td>Name </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cname'] ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Rating Type </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ttitle'] ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Action </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['atitle'] ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Outlook </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['otitle'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Long Term Rating </td>
            <td>Current (<?php echo $row['ltitle'] ?>) <tr><td>Previous (<?php echo $row['ltitle'][0] ?>)</td> </tr></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Short Term Rating </td>
            <td>Current (<?php echo $row['stitle'] ?>) <tr><td>Previous (<?php echo $row['stitle'][0] ?>)</td> </tr></td>
        </tr>


</table>

</body>
</html>

<?php
}?>
```

Result of my code is

[image: result]

In Previos column of my code i want to print second row data of my db table. 
You can see my result is wrong. Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Have you printed out results in php without adding html code? I suggest you do this first.

Comment: @cedricliang i post an image of my query result which is without html

Comment: Try change DESC to ASC in your sql?

Comment: @cedricliang not working yet

Comment: Maybe you can use "Select ** ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 2" to select two rows, and then call "rows = $result->fetch_all(); ". just use the second row of the results.

Comment: @cedricliang can you explain it i am new in PHP

Comment: Say if you have two rows returning from sql. "while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())" will iterate the row one by one until end of the rows. But "$result->fetch_all()" can return two rows at onetime, so that you don't have to use "while" to get all rows.

Comment: @cedricliang but i dont want to return whole data of second row.

Comment: Right, that's what i mean in previous comment. For avoiding that, you should modify you sql. Try "ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 1,1" to get the second row directly.

Comment: @cedricliang i want to print first row completely and only two columns from second row. Not only second row completely. :(

Comment: Use "$result->fetch_all();" to get all tow rows into an array. Then iterate the array using for loop. Print different data as you wish by distinguishing it's first or second row.

Comment: @cedricliang Thank you so much i have done :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85202/discussion-between-sunny-and-cedricliang).

Answer (score 2):

Modify sql with "ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 1,1" to get the second row directly :)

Comment: Thank You So much. By your hint i do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo...!!! I have done it. Thank You [cedricliang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143748/cedricliang) for my help

Just look at my updated code below

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$id2 = $_GET['id'];
$sql= "SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= 338
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1";


$sql1= "SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle, s.title as stitle
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= 338
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1,1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
//$array = array('1','2','3');

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td> ID </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['client_id'] ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
            <td>Name </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cname'] ?> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Rating Type </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ttitle'] ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Action </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['atitle'] ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Outlook </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['otitle'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Long Term Rating </td>
            <td>Current (<?php echo $row['ltitle'] ?>) <tr><td>Previous (<?php echo $row1['ltitle'] ?>)</td> </tr></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Short Term Rating </td>
            <td>Current (<?php echo $row['stitle'] ?>) <tr><td>Previous (<?php echo $row1['stitle'] ?>)</td> </tr></td>
        </tr>


</table>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    }
}?>
```

And the result of my code is

[image: result]